How to hide header of values in matrix?
I am not sure how to properly do this, or if it is even possible.
I have a matrix that looks like this:

And I want it to look like this:

I tried turning off the text wrap and adjusted the column width until they disappear, but the output looks uneven and off.
Here it is:


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Search for blank (invisible) character and copy-paste on your measure/column name:


That's great! Although that would remove the labels under total as well, which I'm not aiming for.
